# php table add values if cell repeats

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have a wordpress loop retriving a table like this:

[image]

I want to check if the name  repeats it self and if so do a sum of partial values to show the total. 
On my screenshot the 1st and 3rd rows have the same "nome" so the global value should be 85, can any one tellme how to do this ?

my php :

```
<?php while( have_rows('wallet_repeater') ): the_row(); 

echo '<div class="promotoras_item_wallet">  ';
echo '<div class="promnames_wallet">  ';
// vars

$adicionados = get_sub_field('wallet_promotora');

  foreach($adicionados as $post) :

$nome = simple_fields_values("pname1");
$im = simple_fields_values("ftotop");
$cp=$adicionados ;
$imatop = $im; 
$data=get_sub_field('wallet_data');
$evento=get_sub_field('wallet_evento');
$obs=get_sub_field("wallet_obs");  
$numeros_horas = get_sub_field("Wallet_n_horas");
$valor_horas = get_sub_field("wallet_valorh");
$evento = get_sub_field("wallet_evento");
$horarios = get_sub_field("wallet_horario");

$total_parcial = $valor_horas * $numeros_horas."€";
$ii = wp_get_attachment_image($imatop[0]);


?>

<table id="wallet_table1" width="900px" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">

      <td class="wallet_data_img" width="5"><div class="w_promotora_images"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($imatop[0]);  ?></td>
      <td class="wallet_data_data" width="20"><?php echo the_sub_field('wallet_data'); ?> </td>
      <td class="wallet_data_nome" width="200"><?php echo $nome[0];$nomes[]=$nome[0];?></td>
      <td class="wallet_data_evento" width="10"> <?php echo the_sub_field("wallet_evento"); ?></td>
      <td class="wallet_data_horarios" width="10"><?php echo the_sub_field("wallet_horario");  ?></td>
      <td class="wallet_data_obs" width="10"><?php echo the_sub_field("wallet_obs"); ?></td>
      <td class="wallet_data_horas" width="10"><?php echo the_sub_field("Wallet_n_horas")."h"; ?></td>
      <td class="wallet_data_valorh" width="5"><?php echo the_sub_field("wallet_valorh")."€"; ?></td>
      <td class="wallet_data_props" width="5"><?php echo the_sub_field("wallet_props"); ?></td>
      <td class="wallet_data_total" width="5">Parcial: <?php echo $total_parcial; ?> global: 

</td> </tr></tbody></table>


<?php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stuff the query data into an associative array and after that output it.
You can do it like that:

```
$qry = new WP_Query('post_type' => 'your_post_type', 'posts_per_page' => -1)
$arr = array();
while($qry->have_posts()) {
    $qry->the_post()
    $nam = //Get the name data;
    $val = //Get the «global» data;
    if($qry[$nam]) {
        $qry[$nam]['global'] += $val;
    }
    else {
        $qry[$nam] = array(
            'foto' => //Photo data of the current post,
            'name' => //Photo data of the current post,
            //and so on
            'global' => $val,
        );
    }
}
foreach($qry as $key => $data) {
    //Output your table here
}
```

Comment: i get my infos like this:
<?php while( have_rows('wallet_repeater') ): the_row();                               <td class="wallet_data_nome" width="200"><?php echo $nome[0];$nomes[]=$nome[0];?></td>

Comment: so, just get your data inside while-loop and put it in the right places (where comments are)

Comment: in foreach-loop $key - is the name, so you can use it or duplicate it inside array and use it like `$data['name']`

Comment: sorry im kinda new to loops... i just edit my question with my code  ! maybe u can help now i tryed to edit ur code but no joy...  i want if wallet_data_nome repeats to do a sum of $total_parcial and display it on row that says global ... ! tks for helping . really appreciated

Comment: First of all I don't see where you close while and foreach loops.
Second, $adicionados should be an array for foreach loop to work. If $adicionados is not array then there is no need in foreach-loop

Comment: hi codeartist .. i have an array now (check my Answers 2) but i have no clue how to do the rest  :/